# Confused by `ai_game` in Ship class where a ship (shooter) object is defined for a Pygame project

Tags: python, class, oop, python-import, python-module

I'm learning python through Python Crash Course and I'm stuck in 12th chapter. I just can't understand the reason behind creating `ai_game` instance in the code below where It's trying to define a `ship` object for an Alien Shooting game using Pygame. Wasn't it possible to use `self.screen` only and just skip `ai_game`? Why is it not even used anywhere else in the program? I'm just confused.

```
# ship.py module
import pygame

class Ship:
   *** def __init__(self, ai_game):
        self.screen = ai_game.screen
        self.screen_rect = ai_game.screen.get_rect()***

        self.image = pygame.image.load('images/ship_graphic.bmp')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        self.rect.midbottom = self.screen_rect.midbottom

    def blitme(self):
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

and below is the main module of the game:

````
import sys
import pygame

from settings import Settings
from ship import Ship


class AlienInvasion:
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()
        self.imported_settings = Settings()

        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode(
            (self.imported_settings.screen_width,
                self.imported_settings.screen_height))

        self.back_ground_color_attribute = self.imported_settings.background_color
        pygame.display.set_caption('Alien Invasion')
        self.ship = Ship(self)

    def run_game(self):
        while True:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    sys.exit()

            self.screen.fill(self.back_ground_color_attribute)
            self.ship.blitme()

            pygame.display.flip()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ai = AlienInvasion()
    ai.run_game()
```
````

Comment: Ship object is created and has to be drawn on to the screen object that's external to it. Even though `Ship` has a `self.screen` attribute, it doesn't know how to reference the actual screen that the game uses so we need to provide it an instance of the game itself. This way the game screen can be utilised by all objects.

Comment: I suspect the choice of passing the whole `AlienInvasion` instance rather than just the screen is a future-proofing effort. In the future, the `Ship` might need additional information stored in the `ai_game` value, even if right now it only uses its the `screen` attribute.

Comment: Hi, I'm the author of PCC. @Blckknght is correct; we pass the whole `ai_game` instance so we can later access any attribute of the game we need. Here's the [final version](https://github.com/ehmatthes/pcc_3e/blob/main/chapter_14/scoring/ship.py) of ship.py, at the end of the project. We end up accessing the screen object, and the settings object. You could just pass each of those separately, but one of my goals in this project is to minimize the number of arguments that need to be passed around.

Comment: In the first edition of the book, the entire game was function based. It worked, but there were way too many arguments being passed around. Look at the [call](https://github.com/ehmatthes/pcc/blob/master/chapter_14/alien_invasion.py#L39) to `check_events()` at the end of the project in the first edition. That was really problematic; if you switch the order of any of those arguments, the game doesn't run. In the 2nd and 3rd edition, I don't think any method call has more than two arguments. It's a little more complex at the start of the project, but much cleaner as the game evolves.